# Identity 3 - store claims in database but not cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In.net core Identity 3 - is it possible to NOT store user claims or role claims in the Identity cookie by default but have them in the database only?

In other words if you want to access the claims you would have to load them explicitly.

Haven't been able to figure out how to configure this using the built in functionality of Identity and the default schema.

Comment: but why? Cookie is encrypted and nobody but you will get access to it.

Comment: The issue is not whether it is encrypted or not or how secure it is.  The issue is that the cookie is becoming too large.  I have many role claims and it is becoming too big to send in the Http header.

Comment: Ah, that's fair enough then. One work-around I can see is not to put all your data into claims, but rather keep this information separate and query it by `user.Id` - you are going to query database anyway, does it matter where you query to get the data: claims table or your own structure?

Comment: That's a very good point and I was thinking about that too -  I may have to go this route.  Since Identity gives you the AspNetRoleClaims table out of the box was just trying to get it to work with that - and I thought I could perhaps selectively control which claims went into the cookie to control the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to still use the built in AspNetRoleClaims table but not including these in the cookie by overriding the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory class.  Again the reason for this is that I have many role claims and the cookie was becoming too large.

I created my own class, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory that inherits from UserClaimsPrincipalFactory and overrides the CreateAsync method:

```
public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }
    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var userName = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType,
            Options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, userId));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, userName));
        if (UserManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType,
                await UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user)));
        }

        // code removed that adds the role claims 

        if (UserManager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            id.AddClaims(await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
        }
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs ConfigureServices, I then register this with the container like so:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // override UserClaimsPrincipalFactory (to remove role claims from cookie )
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: Option.Cookie doesn't seem to supported anymore in 2.1: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L79

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to not implement the IUserClaimStore interface on the UserStore implementation. The default implementation which comes as part of the EF package does implement this interface, so the claims are stored and retrieved automatically.